# HTML element attribute values across indented whitespace?

Tags: html, whitespace, indentation, entity-attribute-value

Instead of:

`<a href="http://really-exceptionally-ridiculously-long-example.com">go</a>`

I'd like:

`<a href="http://really-exceptionally-
    ridiculously-long-example.com">go</a>`

But this is invalid because of the whitespace indentation.

While I could do:

`<a href="http://really-exceptionally-
ridiculously-long-example.com">go</a>`

I would like to have pretty formatted source. And that means no long lines and proper whitespace indentation.

Is there a difference between different versions of HTML/XHTML?

Comment: i think new line is perfectly fine in validation

Comment: You're right. I see my error. I'll edit.

Comment: There are several old questions that answer the question in the title. The body of the question seems to ask how to *include* a newline in an attribute value so that is not significant.

Comment: Now the question has changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attribute value that is declared to be a URL, such as an `href` attribute value, must not contain whitespace at all (by [generic URL syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)), except that [HTML5 permits](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href) whitespace *around* the URL. (%-encoded whitespace such as `%20` is permitted, but it then means that the actual URL contains whitespace.)

So you simply cannot break an `href` attribute value across lines, or to have spaces inside the URL.

If you wish to reduce line length in HTML source in your example, you cannot thus get any shorter than here:

```
<a href=
http://really-exceptionally-ridiculously-long-example.com
>go</a>
```

Quotation marks are not required around attributes like this, in browser practice or by [HTML5 rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) (HTML 4.01 is more restrictive, and so are all versions of XHTML).

Comment: Thank you. Can you cite this, please?

Comment: I added some references and an example.